# How to deploy app remotely via ninja build system using qtcreator

Tags: cmake, qt-creator, ninja

I want to deploy my qt app to a remote Linux device. I use **qtcreator**, **cmake**, and the **ninja** build system. But when I want to debug my app remotely via ssh, I got following error:

```
ninja: error: unknown target 'install'
15:56:22: The process "/usr/bin/cmake" exited with code 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [Deploying CMake Projects to Embedded Linux Devices](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-deployment-embedded-linux.html#deploying-cmake-projects-to-embedded-linux-devices). Depending on that you can just

1. Add following lines to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

   ```
   file(WRITE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/QtCreatorDeployment.txt" "<deployment/prefix>\n")

   macro(add_deployment_file SRC DEST)
       file(RELATIVE_PATH path ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
       file(APPEND "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/QtCreatorDeployment.txt" "${path}/${SRC}:${DEST}\n")
   endmacro()

   macro(add_deployment_directory SRC DEST)
       file(GLOB_RECURSE files RELATIVE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" "${SRC}/*")
       foreach(filename ${files})
           get_filename_component(path ${filename} PATH)
           add_deployment_file("${filename}" "${DEST}/${path}")
       endforeach(filename)
   endmacro()

   add_deployment_file(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME} /path/to/remote/app)
   ```
2. From `QtCreator` go to `Projects/Run` and just delete `Install into temporary host directory` step in Deployment.